# Circular/directional data analysis within a narrow arc

Tags: circular-statistics

I am studying the presence of an anatomical variation to the structure of a long bone in healthy and diseased individuals. I have two separate groups of individuals. The anatomical variation is torsion of long bone which sounds simple enough but not according to my reviewers. The big headache is that some individuals in both groups have a reversed direction of torsion. The majority are externally rotated; however; some are internally rotated.

1. How do I convert circular data to linear?
2. What do I use to test for Gaussian distribution?
   3.Once I get past the distribution, what test do I use to compare? Is Mann-Whitney U test OK to use?
3. Side-to side variability - left to right. Each pair of limbs regardless of disease status are torsed in the same direction.

The range of both groups is fairly narrow but in two opposite directions. Healthy individuals range (-5.44 degrees internal to + 6.39 external)
Diseased individuals (-26.55 internal to +25.15) However when plotted on a compass rose the two groups' ranges hardly overlap.

I used (+) to determine external and (-) to determine internal torsion
I am not a professional statistician so please go easy on me.

---

The original data set describing the geometry of the transverse axis (about 70
data pairs per specimen) was treated similarly as described for the longitudinal
axis. Again, a normalised natural coordinate s was constructed such that 0 6 s 6 1,
s = 0 at the medial border of the medial coronoid process and s = 1 at the lateral
border of the medial coronoid process and the original Cartesian z–x reference
frame (Fig. 2D) of each set of data was translated so that the medial border of the
medial coronoid process was located at (z0, x0) = (0, 0). Sixth-order polynomial
curve fits were performed (highest r2 = 0.9996, lowest r2 = 0.9933, mean
r2 = 0.9981) and the x-coordinates were calculated for intervals of 0.025 (i.e.
s = 0.025, 0.05, 0.075, 0.1, . . . , 1). The resulting series of 40 data set pairs characterised
the geometry of the medial coronoid process at its transverse axis and was
used for further calculations. The inclination angle b of the transverse axis of the
medial coronoid process was calculated trigonometrically using the original coordinates
of the first and last data set pair. Four joints (Table 1) were excluded from this
analysis because the contour of the articular surface was not flat (like in all other
joints) but had deep steps related to high degree subchondral bone erosion.

Comment: I don't know whether "torsed" is part of anatomical vocabulary in English.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a professional statistician either, but I've been dealing with directional data for a few decades.

I see no reason with this kind of data to over-emphasise their origin (pun intended) as angles. Two simple acid tests for deciding when you really need directional or circular statistics are that (a) in principle, essentially any direction is possible (b) you realise that the usual mean is not helpful, as when the mean of 1$^\circ$ and 359$^\circ$ is returned as 180$^\circ$.

That doesn't seem likely here. Indeed, in contrast to the usual situation for circular data in which the origin is arbitrary (e.g. South at 0$^\circ$ would be equally (un)satisfactory compared with North at 0$^\circ$), the origin at 0$^\circ$ seems entirely natural here.

I don't know why Mann-Whitney should spring to mind here. You give no information at all that could help us advise whether the Gaussian or normal is an acceptable reference distribution here.

Summary: When directions cover part of the circle, treating them as linear is both simpler and defensible. In your case, the origin doesn't seem arbitrary, so stick with it.

Note: Circular data being treated as linear does not make trigonometry irrelevant, although in this case, with small angles, the possible transformation sine of angle is essentially linear in angle over the ranges observed.

Comment: Let me be a bit more specific.  Simplistically, the angle is formed by the crossing of the two reference lines at both ends of a cylinder. So 0 is formed when both lines are parallel.  The problem is that the torsion can go in both directions. if a compass rose is used 0 to 360.  The conundrum is that healthy individuals have a rage of ~354 degrees to 5 degrees cross the 0 while diseased individuals have a range from ~8 to 355 in the opposite direction. My goal is to compare both populations in therms of the degree of torsion.

Comment: The journal statistician by the clobbered me for ignoring the directionality of the data

Comment: Your comments are helpful and don't change my view here one little bit. But it should be easy to show that (e.g.) orthodox means and circular means are similar. Why not post your data? Presumably they aren't confidential or sensitive without personal identifiers?

Comment: No. The data is not personal or confidential. Just quite a bit of it. This is my first time on this forum. So I am not even sure where to begin.

Comment: Right now I am working on converting it to linear so I can assess normality. Kolmogorov–Smirnov Test

Comment: In my view it's linear already. K-S test is a poor way to assess normality; use a normal quantile plot.

Comment: go tell it to the reviews. I sure you know how blinded peer reviews go

Comment: I did MWU test to determine statistical significance and ROC curve to determine cut off point. I also did side to side variability via independent t test. The journal statistician suggested that I model this paper in terms of statistical analysis. Breit, Pfeiffer and Pichler (2010),

Comment: is there a way to attach file in here?

Comment: Better to edit your question and give more detail: e.g. ROC curve to determine the cut-off point; no idea what that means. MWU test: perhaps you mean Mann-Whitney U. No idea what Breit et al. is: you should give full reference rather than assume we know all literature.

Comment: I would love to send you the whole paper. Let me know how. The Receiver Operator Characteristic curve is a way to compare the diagnostic usefulness of a test. My goal is to use the torsion angle as a diagnostic marker for early detection of the disease before is has become clinical.

Comment: Best to treat the forum as a shared site where anyone inclined can read and comment, not as a way to elicit private support.

Comment: I am not sure why are you say that. If I can post the paper here I would. I just don see a way of doing it. I have ran this data set through about 4 different scenarios and now I am confused which one to use for the re write.

Comment: Again this is my first time here. So I apologize if I am breaking any rules inadvertently.

Comment: It's simple. Many of us volunteer a few minutes' thought if we think we can contribute usefully to a reasonably concise question. Conversely when people post an entire paper they often seem to expect that others will read it all, which is less likely. No rules here, just that's it is good to be practical over what you ask.

Comment: I understand. What is was suggesting is share the paper that I was pointed to as an illustration of that I am asked to do.

Comment: As said, a full reference is a good idea. If there is a URL you can share, that is fine too.

Comment: Yes. That I was waiting for.

Comment: I posted a piece of the normalization analysis. Let see if that helps

Comment: Well. Thank you for your correction. My blood is up from fighting with the reviewers. It is very clear that one of the guys did not read the whole paper on top of admitting that he did not understand the statistics. Here is where I am heading now. I will bow to pressure and analyze the data as circular.  Found this software called Oriana that specializes in circular data analysis and I will give it a try. Will keep you posted. One last question. I have a difficulty distinguishing circular from axial data. Can you help?